# Generate random numbers whose sum is equal to a constant value modulo n

Tags: randomness, modular-arithmetic

I want to generate $n$ random numbers $u_i \in [ 0, 2^{\kappa + 1})$ such that $\sum u_i = c$ $mod$ $2^{\kappa + 1} $, where c is a constant.
Also, taking $n - 1$ random numbers and subtracting their sum from $b \cdotp 2^{\kappa + 1} + c$, where $b \cdotp 2^{\kappa + 1}$ is the closest multiple of $\;2^{\kappa + 1}$ that is greater than sum of the $n - 1$ random numbers, to get the $n^{th}$ random number a good solution?

P.S. I want to know if there's a solution to this problem that'll ensure good statistical properties.

Comment: And the summation is the only criteria for u's distribution?

Comment: Yes, that's the only criteria. Although, I'd like to know if I can get uniformly distributed random numbers that satisfy this condition.

Comment: So my answer was wrong, and I don't know of a way to prove that extending the simplex idea to modular arithmetic. I'll delete it in a moment. I do think your proposed idea is a good one, but this is just speculation. [The top answer here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1276206/method-of-generating-random-numbers-that-sum-to-100-is-this-truly-random) may be useful.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For $i=1, \dots, n-1$, generate $n-1$ random numbers $u_i \in [0,2^{κ+1})$ and define $u_n = \left(c - \sum_{i=1}^{n-1} u_i\right) \bmod 2^{κ+1}$.

Comment: That's the idea I proposed. I want to know if it is a good way to solve this problem because when a similar solution was posed to the problem of generating n prime numbers who have a constant sum, many people said that it is not a good way of solving that problem.

Comment: That's optimal. When $n>1$, it is easily proven that each $u_i$ generated is uniformly random in $[0,2^{κ+1})$: that's by construction for $u_i$ with $i<n$, and for $u_n$ that follows from the fact that $u_{n-1}$ is uniformly random in $[0,2^{κ+1})$, and$$u_n=\left(c - \sum_{i=1}^{n-2} u_i\right)-u_{n-1}\bmod2^{κ+1}$$